# song guessing game with hashing

Tags: python, game, console, csv

I have created a CLI python game that allows for the creation of local accounts and the data is stored in local .csv files. The passwords are hashed so can be stored securely. It keeps track of the players score and has a leaderboard. I created this in my freetime for my computer science gcse programming test.

I have uploaded all files onto my github: https://github.com/excal-rs/song-guesser

the code works as intended

my code:

```py
# Excal-rs Github

import bcrypt
import os
import pandas as pd

# Create a list of all used usernames for later reference
accountbase = pd.read_csv("Accounts.csv")
usernames = accountbase["Username"].tolist()


# Handles Hashing and storing passwords and usernames
class UserDetail:
    def __init__(self, username, password, score):
        self.username = username
        self.hpassword = bcrypt.hashpw((password).encode("utf-8"), bcrypt.gensalt())
        self.score = score
        # hashes the passcode so it can be stored securely
        df = pd.DataFrame({"Username": [self.username],
                           "password": [self.hpassword.decode("utf-8")],
                           "score": [self.score]})

        # writes username and hashed password to the csv file
        df.to_csv("Accounts.csv", mode="a", index=False, header=False)


def prelogin():
    choice = str(input("Do you already have an account? ")).lower()

    while choice not in ['y', 'yes', 'no', 'n']:
        choice = str(input(f"Sorry but \"{choice}\" is not a valid response, please try again! \n"
                           f"Do you have an account? "))

    if choice in ['n', 'no']:
        createUser()

    elif choice in ['y', 'yes', '']:
        print("")

    else:
        print("Incorrect input Please try again")
        prelogin()


# Subprogram to create a new user if needed
def createUser():
    print("\nOK! Let's make an account for you!")
    username = str(input("What do you want to be called? "))

    while username in usernames:
        username = str(input("Sorry, that username is already taken! \nPlease enter another username: "))
    # Ensures there are no duplicate usernames by checking all usernames in use
    if username not in usernames:

        password = str(input("Please enter password: "))
        # os.system('cls')  #only works on Windows machines (cant test as I am using Arch)
        passwordconf = str(input("Please confirm password: "))

        while password != passwordconf:
            # os.system('cls')
            print("Sorry those passwords don't match! Try again. ")

            password = str(input("Please enter password: "))
            # os.system('cls')
            passwordconf = str(input("Please confirm password: "))

        print("Thank you for making an account, you can now log in! \n")
        UserDetail(username, password, 0)


def Login():

    accountbase = pd.read_csv("Accounts.csv")
    usernames = accountbase["Username"].tolist()
    # Updates usernames list to compesate for new user creation

    username = str(input("Please enter account username: "))
    password = str(input("Please enter account password: ")).encode("utf-8")

    while True:
        if username not in usernames:
            print("That user does not exist! Do you want to create a new user?")
            x = input().lower()
            if x in ['y',"yes"]:
                createUser()
                Login()
                break
            elif x not in ['y', 'yes']:
                print("OK, Let's try again!")

                username = str(input("Please enter account username: "))
                password = str(input("Please enter account password: ")).encode("utf-8")

        elif username == accountbase.loc[GetRow(username), 'Username'] and \
                bcrypt.checkpw(password, (accountbase.loc[GetRow(username), 'password']).encode("utf-8")):

            print("You have successfully logged in! \n")
            break

        elif username == accountbase.loc[GetRow(username), 'Username'] and \
                bcrypt.checkpw(password, (accountbase.loc[GetRow(username), 'password']).encode("utf-8")) == False:

            print("Incorrect username or password! Please try again! \n")
            username = str(input("Please enter account username: "))
            password = str(input("Please enter account password: ")).encode("utf-8")

    return username


# Fetches the index for row of user for future reference e.g. score
def GetRow(username):
    accountbase = pd.read_csv("Accounts.csv")
    index = accountbase.index[accountbase["Username"] == username].tolist()
    index = index[0]
    return index


# Main part of program
def songguess(score):
    print("Enter \"End Now\" as a guess to end game ")
    songbase = pd.read_csv("Songbase.csv")
    total_rows = len(songbase.axes[0])

    for i in range(total_rows):
        songbase = pd.read_csv('Songbase.csv')
        song = songbase.loc[i, 'song'].lower()
        artist = songbase.loc[i, 'artist'].lower()

        songinitial = ' '.join(song[0] for song in song.split()).replace(" ", ".")

        guess = str(input(f"What song is {songinitial} - by {artist}: "))

        if guess == "end" and input("Are you sure? y/n") in ["yes", "y"]:
            break

        elif guess == song:
            score += 1
            print(f"That is correct \nYour score is now: {score} \n")
            continue

        elif song != guess:
            print("Incorrect! You have two more attempts before you lose a point!\n")

            for x in range(2):
                guess = str(input(f"What song is {songinitial} - by {songbase.artist[i]}: "))
                if x == 1 and guess != song:
                    score = score - 1
                    print(f"You have lost one point! Your score is now: {score}\n")
                    break

                elif guess == "end now" and input("Are you sure? y/n") in ["yes", "y"]:
                    break

                elif guess == song:
                    score += 1
                    print(f"That is correct \nYour score is now: {score} \n")
                    break

                elif guess != song:
                    print("incorrect, one more try!")
                    continue

                elif guess != song:
                    print("incorrect, one more try!")
                    continue

        continue
    return score


def SortLeaderboard(lb):
    lb.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])
    return lb


# Allows for choice of account creation through previous subprogram
prelogin()

Uname = Login()

accountbase = pd.read_csv("Accounts.csv")
score = accountbase.loc[GetRow(Uname), 'score']

# os.system('cls')

print(f"Welcome to the song guesser game! Your score is currently {score} !"
      f" Lets try get it higher so u can be on the leaderboard")

score = songguess(score)

print("Thank you for playing! :) ")

accountbase.loc[GetRow(Uname), 'score'] = score
accountbase.to_csv('Accounts.csv', index=False)

print("Are you on the leaderboard? \n")

for count in range(len(accountbase.index)):
    leaderboard = []
    leaderboard = ((accountbase[['Username', 'score']]).values.tolist())

df = pd.DataFrame(SortLeaderboard(leaderboard), columns=['Username', 'Score'])
print(df)

df.to_csv('Leaderboard.csv', index=False, header=True)

input()

# GitHub Excal-rs
```